# Blob stored in FileSystem as Video source: "Not allowed to load local resource"

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, blob, html5-filesystem

Having to serve users video files that may be watched several times each one, I tried to implement some caching strategy. Note that the application is restricted to working on Chrome only.

Videos are downloaded as Blobs, then stored to FileSystem.
Later, Blobs are retrieved from the FileSystem and handed to the video.src through URL.createObjectURL(blob)

Everything worked fine on localhost. But once moved to the server, the same code causes Chrome to throw "Not allowed to load local resource" at the time video.src is set.

Is this related to same-origin policy? I wonder because the usual exceptions are not thrown.
Also: what would the use of locally stored files be, if then it seems to be impossible to use them within the DOM without incurring in the above error?

Hope someone can shed some light, thanks.

Comment: Try the extension to disable origin and see -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: Thanks I'll try (unfortunately it's not easy for me to download extension, I live in China and even with a VPN Google seems to be suffering a complete blockage now. Chrome can't even update properly). Anyway an extension wouldn't be a viable solution, unfortunately.

Comment: I never said it was a solution, i said to see if that's the problem. If you read the info you can do it manually from a command prompt. Just dir to the google chrome folder and type -- (chrome --disable-web-security) -- if it is a problem then you need to read this --- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr -- good luck

Comment: Right, thanks. Done, but the problem stays. My guts are telling me that this is some half-botched implementation of the specs I am working against.. just a feeling, though

Comment: the problem will stay because i assume you are using (file://myvideo) to get the videos. That wont work. Disabling security will work with ajax GET file. You need to load the data first then display the video. -- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ .. i had the same issue once as a test i thought to give it a go and eventually gave up. You need some server side implementation to send the correct headers to the browser as it wont allow you to access files form the local disk drive and load them directly in the browser

Comment: No I am not using file://. I download a video from the webserver using XMLHttpRequest and responsetype = 'blob'. Once the blob is downloaded, I get an URL to it through URL.createObjectURL(). Finally, I assign the URL to the video. This works entirely, either on a local or remote server. The problem starts after I store the above blob into the local FileSystem ( http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ ). On the 2nd run I should retrieve the blob from there, as a form of caching. I retrieve it correctly. I get its url correctly. But then I can't assign it to the video src.